# making request to yahoo API from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, oauth

I'm trying to make requests from my Node server to a Yahoo API so I can get some data for my application. Yahoo APIs use Oauth and I can't find an example using Node and Oauth together. I looked at the http.request method in the Node docs, but their auth example is just 'user: password' Does anyone know how I can pass my oauth keys in my requests?

Comment: Use this https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth

Comment: @BidhanA I can't believe I never saw this. I was trying to work with Oauth.io but they don't support all the API I want to use.

Comment: I've used it with Twitter and Yahoo myself. Works quite well.

Comment: @BidhanA is this being maintained? the link to examples is dead and the README and package.json are the only things sort of recently updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request` libary, it support `OAuth`, here is the example:
https://github.com/request/request#oauth-signing

You can try it.